# GET request to a different HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am using HTML, JQuery and NodeJS. My issue is that I am trying to post a form from index.html to Node, process (database, etc), respond with JSON to JQuery and also redirect. So I want to process the json response and view it on a different HTML page (board.html).

To do that I am trying to include the same JS file on both HTML pages (index.html, board.html) I post the data from index that works but after the redirect to board.html JS doesn't load the content on board.html:

I tried

```
window.location.replace("/views/board.html");
$('#b-content').append("content...").after('topic: '+res.topic);
```

```
//index.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("READY!")
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('action', 'api/board/:b')
      $.ajax({
        url: '/api/board/:b',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#main-form').serialize(),
        success: function(res) {
          window.location.replace("/views/board.html");
          $('#b-content').append("content...").after('topic: '+res.topic);
          $('#responses').append("topic: <h3>" + res.topic + "</h3>");
        }
      });
      // e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

// back-end

```
  app.route('/api/board/:b')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    compiledObject = {
      board: req.body.board,
      user: req.body.name,
      topic: req.body.topic,
      thread: req.body.thread
    };
    res.json(compiledObject);
  })
```

// index.html sample

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>
        Anon Message Board
      </h1>
    </header>
    <div id="form-div">
      <form id="main-form" method="post" action="">
        username:
        <input type="text" placeholder="coolname" name="name"/><br>
        <label for="general">General</label>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="general"></span>
        <label for="tech">Tech</label>
        <input type="radio" name="topic" value="tech"><br>
        board:
        <input type="text" name="board" /><br>
        message:
        <textarea name="thread" ></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="responses">
      <p id="res-name"></p>
    </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="views/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

// board.html sample

```
  <body>
    <h1>Board:</h1>
    <div id="b-content">
      <p>content ...</p>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/views/index.js"></script>
  </body>
....
```

I can get the board.html to load but the appended elements do not load.

Comment: If you redirect you can not do anything to the DOM. So the lines after the replace are useless. You also are not cancelling the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once this fires:

```
window.location.replace("/views/board.html");
```

you are requesting a new page from your server, therefore all the logic you have done on the index page is gone. You need to store the data you have received from the index page in either `LocalStorage` or in a `cookie` BEFORE you redirect.

so your logic should be something like

```
get data
listen for error
if error dont redirect and tell user
if no error, store the data you received, then redirect to new page
load data into your new page
```

also you may want to think about what exactly your app is doing and how the flow works. Should you be redirecting to a new page every time a user posts a message?

Comment: Yes, thanks; I didn't know much about web storage before; that sounds like a good approach. 
Also, I think it's best to have separate JS files for each html page ... I couldn't get both pages to be controlled from index.js even though I included the script on both html pages

Answer (score 1):

The expected functionality you are looking for is what is called state management.  You want one page to alter the state of another page.  If I were you, I would use the browser's `localStorage` to save data that you retrieve before routing, especially if you aren't using a framework/plugin that supports state management.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful I didn't know much regarding local web storage.